# Visit Pompeii on may 1st

Tags: italy, pompeii

I've learned that in Italy, the 1st May is labor day so all museums are closed, but I can't find informations if the visit of pompeii will be closed too.

Same thing for the mount Vesuvius, will labor day affect buses going near the top? Will it be accessible on May 1st?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you'll find websites telling you Pompeii is closed on May 1st, like this:
http://www.pompei.biz/pompei/orario_scavi.htm
However, I know for a fact that's not always the case. It was open on May 1st in 2009 and 2015.
I don't really know about the Vesuvius but I found this:
http://eventinapoli.com/eventi/il-primo-maggio-scalata-al-vesuvio
Sorry, that's all I got.